# How can background-image affect a border-style of none or hidden?

Tags: css, border

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) states that

> Unless a background-image is set, the computed value of the same
> side's border-width will be 0, even if the specified value is
> something else.

How would a background-image make border-width nonzero even if border-style is set to none or hidden?

Comment: give the link of the MDN

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style

Comment: Not sure but it seems to be a *computed* value only but not an actual one from my quick testing.

Comment: The quote doesn't make sense to me, honestly. You could try the "Report a problem with this content on GitHub" link at the bottom of that page.